# Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't

Tags: dart

Good day,
I have been trying the below code:

```
import 'dart:io';
main (){
print ("write your birth year:");
var birthyear = stdin.readLineSync();
var birthyearint = int.parse(birthyear);
var age = 2021-birthyearint;
print(age);
}
```

when I run it I receive the following error:

5:30: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
var birthyearint = int.parse(birthyear);
^

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error is caused by the null safety feature in Dart, see https://dart.dev/null-safety.

The result of method `stdin.readLineSync()` is `String?`, i.e. it may be a `String`, or it may be `null`. The method `int.parse()` requires a (non-null) `String`. You should check that the user gave some input, then you can assert that the value is non-null using `birthyear!`. Better still, you should use `int.tryParse()` to check that the user input is a valid integer, for example:

```
var birthyearint = int.tryParse(birthyear ?? "");
if (birthyearint == null) {
    print("bad year");
} else {
    var age = 2021-birthyearint;
    print(age);
}
```

Comment: Yeah nullable values in dart creates more problems than they solve - oh well :)

Comment: Please update the answer as, now, arithmetic operation like `var age = 2021-birthyearint` yields an error as `Error: A value of type 'int?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'num' because 'int?' is nullable and 'num' isn't.`

Comment: The error you show implies that `birthyearint` is `int?`, which it is in the first line of my  example code. However, in the else branch, after the test `birthyearint == null` fails, the Dart compiler knows that `birthyearint` is not null, i.e. it is `int`, so no error is raised. (I just checked this is still the case with the latest Dart on `dartpad.dev`.) If you are seeing different behaviour, then test your example code on DartPad, and show the complete code here.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Solution for this error ; just add :  `var birthyear = stdin.readLineSync()`; to read from keyboard; also This error is caused by the null safety feature in Dart: i tried this and successfully passed.
This link may help you : *https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour*
..
.
.
.
.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) (it applies to answers too)