# How to take a integer as input in Dart?

Tags: dart

I was trying to take integer as input in Dart using the following as it is suggested in many sources.

```
import 'dart:io';

  void main() {
  int n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
}
```

But the following error message was shown when I tried to run (Visual Studio Code was also showing it in problems):

Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.

Now how can I take a integer or double as input? (I'm using Dart SDK version: 2.12.2 (stable))

Comment: Two versions of this question were asked yesterday and today. It is recommended to search using the error message to find previous questions before asking a new one. Then you would find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798782/error-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-stri?r=SearchResults&s=1|678.2682

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798782/error-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-stri)

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara No. I am still unable to take input as it doesn't suggest how to take input as integer/double. What I need is a way to take input as inetger/double/string.

Comment: I added a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Null Safety by default with Dart 2.12.2.

[readLineSync()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html) return a `String?` which is a nullable value.

However, [int.parse()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/int/parse.html) take a `String` that cannot be null due to Null Safety. That's what's the error is about.

In order to fix this, you have to check is [readLineSync()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html) return null before using it.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  String? s = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (s != null){
    int n = int.parse(s);
    print(n); // Or do whatever you want with your n value
  }
}
```

Comment: On doing this s !=null condition is not getting satisfied and hence I am unable to take the desired input.

Comment: It works for me. Just add `print(n);` after the parsing.

Comment: Unfortunately not working in mine.

Comment: If you add an else condition with a print, does it go through ?

Comment: Yeah, in that case else condition gets used.

Comment: The dart language pack I am using came with flutter sdk. Is that why problems are arising?

Comment: Me too and there is no problem. Try to print `s` to see what is retrieved by `readLineSync()`

Comment: I tried printing s, I get the input without any problem.

Comment: Ok I found what to do to fix this problem in a telegram group on dart. I had add a ! just after stdin.readLineSync(). Anyway thanks because you tried to help.

Comment: @AnuragPathak oh yeah didn't thought about that but it works too. `!` tells the interpreter that the value is not null and it have to trust you. So here, you tell the interpret that the return of `readLineSync()` cannot be null. However, be careful, if line is empty, the function returns null and you'll have an error.

Answer (score 1):

An example that handles `int`, `double` and `String`:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  String? s = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (s != null) {
    if (int.tryParse(s) != null) {
      int n = int.parse(s);
      print('int $n'); // Or do whatever you want with your int value
    } else if (double.tryParse(s) != null) {
      double d = double.parse(s);
      print('double $d'); // Or do whatever you want with your double value
    } else {
      print('string "$s"'); // Or do whatever you want with your string value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to take input like we do in C/C++, python etc ?

Comment: Surely the Dart `readLineSync` method is comparable to the C `gets` and the Python `input` functions? I do not know of any Dart equivalent of the C `scanf` function.

Comment: But in my case when I take input with readLineSync() the format in which input is taken is string? and when I change it to integer using int.parse(), then always error occurs as mentioned in the question and hence I am unable to take input as integer as well as double and string. Only string? type input is possible.

Comment: The method `readLineSync()` returns a string of characters that the user entered, or null, so the type is String?. It is up to your code to interpret the string. You can interpret it as anything you want, the code above parses the string to see if it is an int, or a double, but you could write code to match any sequence of inputs. (The package https://pub.dev/packages/string_scanner can help here.)