# The argument type 'String"?"' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter

**The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'**

> how can pass the parameter ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#non-nullable-and-nullable-types

Comment: your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798782/error-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-stri)

Comment: yes I saw it but did not understand it @Benyamin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
//...

child: TipsCard(
//...
image: tipsPages[i]["image"] ?? "", // Replace this blank "" with a default image url of your choice
),
```

Comment: it's work thank you but I want to ask you why it's want after initialize char "?" like (String?) and how can remove this feature ? @Bach

Comment: @MSameer This is a feature introduce with Dart 2.0, kind of like a revolution change that make Dart a null-safe language, so the only way to not using it is to convert Dart back to 1.0.  

The `?` is to indicate that the variable can be null. My recommendation is to learn using this feature instead of turning it off, since it'll help us a lot in avoiding potential bugs with null values. There's a quite nice video here from Flutter team: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYhOU9AuaFs

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
child: TipsCard(
//
image:tipsPages[i]["image"] as String,//
)
```