# Dart: The argument type 'Image?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image'

Tags: android, dart, webp, animated-webp

What is the meaning of this error and how to solve it?

Error:

```shell
Animation? decodeImage
The argument type 'Image?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image'
```

Dart Code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';

void main(){

  final image = 'asset/test.webp';

  final bytes = File(image).readAsBytesSync(); // type List<int>
  final decodeImage = decodeWebPAnimation(bytes); // type Animation

  var obj = WebPEncoder(); 

  obj.addFrame(decodeImage?[0]); // gives error

}
```

What are the methods to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try making it non-null bye adding the `bang` (`!`)  like so:

```
  obj.addFrame(decodeImage?[0]!);
```

Comment: Thanks for response. tried ( ! ). but it says it will have no effect.

Comment: Okay isolved. I used  'as Image'

Comment: Try `decodedImage![0]` instead. (Then worry whether you actually can depend on `decodedImage` not being `null`).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using `as [type]`

obj.addFrame(decodeImage?[0] as Image);

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68969699/9308731