# Argument type 'String?' cannot be assigned to parameter type 'String', Triggering Dart's Null Safety either way

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter-notification

In this current snippet I have declared notification to be nullable but get an null safe error for the if loop's notification.body and notification.title.

Here's my code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      debugPrint('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text(notification.title),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [Text(notification.body)],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
}
});
```

If I make 'notification' to be non nullable, I get the same null safe error.

Code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      debugPrint('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text(notification.title),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [Text(notification.body)],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
}
});
```

How to get this to work?

Any help appreciated!

Edit: Added the method name to the coding part.

Comment: Need more details. This line of code are confusing are this method called inside FirebaseNotification listen method ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798782/error-the-argument-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-stri)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things going on here. First, the reason you are getting the null error:

```dart
RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
```

When `notification` is a nullable value, you will get the warning when you attempt to use it without first checking if it is null. Changing it to be non-nullable can resolve the problem, but potentially in a way you don't actually want.

Now when you changed it to non-nullable, you didn't change the line after it:

```
RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
```

Now `notification` is no longer nullable, but you still use a null-coalescing operator when creating `android`. That means that, even though `notification` is non-nullable, `android` still is nullable. From this, you will get two warnings - one for trying to coalesce a non-nullable value, and one for using `android` without checking for null.

The easiest solution would be to make it so `android` is non-nullable as well:

```
RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
AndroidNotification android = message.notification.android;
```

But this might not be possible depending on whether `message.notification` itself is nullable.

---

Now onto the second thing. Assuming we want `notification` and `android` to be nullable, your first null-check isn't enough to eliminate the warning within the callback to `showDialog`. This is because, even though it is known that when `showDialog` is called, `notification` is not null, the analyzer can't know when the callback itself will be called, and by that point, `notification` might have become null. For that reason, the analyzer has no choice but to display the warning regardless of your current null check.

There are four ways to resolve this. First, you could check for null again:

```dart
if (notification != null && android != null) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(notification.title),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [Text(notification.body)],
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        // Return a different widget if null check fails
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Or force non-null with the `!` operator:

```dart
if (notification != null && android != null) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(notification!.title),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [Text(notification!.body)],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Or provide default values in the case that the objects are null:

```dart
if (notification != null && android != null) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(notification?.title ?? 'Default Value'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [Text(notification?.body ?? 'Default Value')],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Or make non-null versions of the objects that the callback can closure around:

```dart
if (notification != null && android != null) {
  final notificationNN = notification;
  final androidNN = android;
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(notificationNN.title),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [Text(androidNN.body)],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's body and title that could be null. A solution is to fallback to empty strings in case they are, like this:

```
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(notification.title ?? ''),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [Text(notification.body ?? '')],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
...
title: Text(notification.title as String),
...
```

Comment: He is getting null value. How can null can be cast to String ?